# Child div is not moving with parent div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive, react-bootstrap

I am just revising html and css, making a login form that contains two div ,y goal is to make the form responsive and its my bad that i totally forget how to make a page responsive i am sticking my code below.

```
.containers {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #2f5496 0%, #613577 100%) 0%
    0% no-repeat padding-box; */
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(47, 84, 150, 0.62),
      rgba(97, 53, 119, 0.93)
    ),
    url("background.png");

  position: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 120%;
}
.form-div {
  position: relative;
  top: 145px;
  left: 491px;
  width: 395px;
  height: 437px;
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 19px #0000003d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

here container is my parent div css class and form div is my login form which i want to align horizontally on the center of the screen. Kindly guide me 
and also help me for understanding bootstrap grid system.

Comment: `position:fixed` is rarely a good idea. Also if you are aiming responsiveness, working with top/left and hardcoded width and height will make that almost impossible. If you need help, please add your HTML code, or at least this part, that is using the currently posted CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in your head in your html

Comment: Can you share the html please

Comment: Also, to understand bootstrap grid system, kindly visit this link : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: and remove  position: relative;
  top: 145px;
  left: 491px;
  width: 395px;
  height: 437px; from your css.